# React.js ,SetCount нужна помощь только начал изучать,но не могу разобраться?

Tags: reactjs

помогите у меня такая проблема только закончил javascript , и уже начали изучать react.js, надо так написать код что бы при нажати на кнопку от задонного x , до y число на один увеличиволось ,а потом дойдя до числа y снова уменшалась, я написал что бы при каждом нажатии от до 100 каждый раз принажатии увеличиволось число на еденицу , а обратно не пойму как реализовать?только на 1 уменщаеться и все?

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Button() {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
let welcome = () => setCountsetCount(count < 100 ? (count + 1) : (count - 1));
return (

{count}
Click

);
}

export default Button;
```